# Finding the minimum ratio out of many lines of input

Tags: php

This is my code. I am having a file, whose first line's second word contains a number. Let this number is `$u`. 2nd line is empty, and from third line, I am given with two numbers separated by a space in each line where let first number is `$c` and second is `$w`. Now I need to figure out the minimum `$b` where `$b` for a line is `ceil($u  / $w) * $c`. Is there anyway I can optimize my code.

```
<?php
$f = file($argv[1]);
list(, $u) = explode(" ", $f[0]);
list($c, $w) = explode(" ", $f[2]);
$b = ceil($u / $w) * $c;
unset($f[0], $f[1], $f[2]);

foreach($f as $l)
{
    list($c, $w) = explode(" ", $l);
    $b = min($b, ceil($u / $w) * $c);
}

echo "$b\n";
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Computers are quick, people are slow.  Maintenance time is huge when you have to work out what each variable is.  Name your variables: $f = $file, $u = $firstLineNumber (or whatever that number really means), etc.

Comment: I want to make computer fast not human. The question is how can I make it better for computers not humans.

Comment: Sourabh: It won't be any slower if you use longer and readable variable names ;-) It helps a lot for the humans who try answering the question :) @Paul: I'd upvote your comment if you write it as an answer...

Comment: If you want to optimize it like that, you should strip out all linebreaks, because then the interpreter will only have to interpret one line. ;)

Comment: Also, there are no "levels"..."next level" doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 4):

I guess my comment really was an answer in a philosophical way.  So here is the answer:

Use names for your variables that have meaning.

There are lots of advantages to naming your variables well.  Many people have looked at this question only with a very abstract idea of what you are trying to do.  This makes it difficult to find improvements.  If people know exactly what you are trying to do then they can work out clever ways to achieve that.

As palacsint said: 'It won't be any slower if you use longer and readable variable names' but it may well be faster when people understand it and can see how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP guru, so the following is more or less just some general idea.

Maybe don't read the whole file in one step. These questions (and comments) could be relevant:

- [PHP Reading Large Text Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496614/php-reading-large-text-files)
- [Fastest way to read a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706529/fastest-way-to-read-a-csv-file)

I wouldn't not think that reading the file line-by-line will make it significantly faster but it may worth a try. (Except if the file is bigger than the size of the free memory.) Since you just do some very simple string parsing and math operations inside the for loop I could imagine it's actually slower than the posted version.

I could imagine that freeing these small memory areas also could slow the running with minimal gain:

```
unset($f[0], $f[1], $f[2]);
```

(If you omit it don't forget to skip the first 3 items inside the `foreach`.)

Changing the double quotes may have some performance benefit especially inside the `foreach` loop. ([Is there a performance benefit single quote vs double quote in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php))

[Using references in the foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#92116) also could have some benefit.

Anyway, you should measure the costs of these (and other) changes.